# .NET Core 2.0 App - MVC works when debugging but not in docker container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have built a very simple .NET Core app (target framework = 2.0), which runs fine when debugging (localhost).....but when I run in docker container on prod server, everything works except the MVC routes.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Environment name: " + env.EnvironmentName);
    });
}
```

`app.UseStaticFiles()` works fine....as `/index.html` path returns the relevant file.
Also the `app.Run()` command works, and returns for all routes that are not calls for static files......Im assuming because the `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` middleware is not being recognized so its passing to the next/final middleware.

Below is my HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello world!!....from Controllers(folder)/HomeController(folder)/Index(function)";
    }
}
```

When I request route `IP/home/index`, it should come back with the Hello World message......it **does** when debugging but **not** when running in docker container

Below is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mpx.dll"]
```

**UPDATE:** I changed HomeController.cs Index method to below....but it didnt help

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello world!!....from Controllers(folder)/HomeController(folder)/Index(function)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what exactly is happening, does it fallback to the inline middleware, is that it?

Comment: Correct - ignores all MVC commands and falls through to app.Run()

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but as a workaround (sorry!), why don't you try adding a [HttpGet] to the Index method?

Comment: First line in the .csproj file = <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

Comment: As @RicardoPeres mentioned, I had to decorate all routes with `[HttpGet]`, `[HttpPost]`, etc. to get it to work in Linux/Docker.

Comment: @JoelMagnuson - I added [HttpGet] to my index method as per my updated question.  Did not work.  p.s. I am using windows/docker, not linux/docker

Comment: Have you tried publishing the project in release and running it locally on your Windows machine, outside of Docker?

Comment: Since it's called `HomeController`, it will automatically pick up the route `/home`.  You might need to add `[HttpGet('/')]`. Also, you might be able to not need a controller for the index page if you use the `IApplicationBuilder app` (`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;`) and `app.UseDefaultFiles();` & `app.UseStaticFiles();`